# UIWebview crashes when I load certain webpages

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, crash, uiwebview

I have been hitting my head against the wall trying to figure this out for two days with no luck. I have a basic UIWebview that is navigating to a page.  That page has a JavaScript function that seems to crash the UIWebView but works just fine in safari.  I am at a loss.  I get the following crash error:

```
2010-02-03 08:30:16.559 Wasp[11380:207] *** -[DOMElement structuralComplexityContribution]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf53e60
2010-02-03 08:30:16.561 Wasp[11380:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[DOMElement structuralComplexityContribution]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf53e60'
```

Thanks for any help or direction.

The problematic JavaScript file is the new gordon flash runtime.  An example can be seen at 
http://davididas.com/gordon/test1.html.

Comment: Please post the problematic JS function. If you remove that function then there is no crash?

Comment: I just edited the original request with the javascript file and a link to where it can be found.  If I remove the javascript the page loads fine, if I load any other page in the UIWebView it functions fine.  The only time it is crashing is when it runs this particular javascript file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File a bug with Apple, with a reference to that page. The `UIWebView` should not crash. Even if the html, css or JavaScript is faulty.